# 'May I speak to....' vs 'May I speak with...' vs 'May I talk to...'

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, politeness, conversation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Speak to” vs. “Speak with”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with)
>   [What is the difference between “speaking” and “talking”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/what-is-the-difference-between-speaking-and-talking)

What is the ideal opening line for a phone conversation? In my opinion, 'speak to' would ideally denote a one-sided conversation and 'talk to' sounds more aggressive than the other 2. Is there a particular telephone etiquette which clarifies this? What is the difference between 'talk' and 'speak'? Also, does the rank/designation/seniority of the other person affect the use of 'speak' or 'talk'?

Comment: No, if it were ideal, it would begin with the forumlaic *“May I **please** ...”*

Answer (score 5):

Nice question, +1.

I think you're right even if they are pretty much interchangeable (consider the context!), and this is shown in the dictionary too.

Even though there are some subtle differences:

- **Talk to:** This one when used like VERB, has the acception of strong discussions, negotiation, or even "(*talk to*) reprimand or scold (someone)". 
  Plus talk has many familiar uses (according to the OED).
- **Speak:** This is inside the entry about the verb "to speak" - **To speak** to another by means of a **telephone**; ― speaking (where ― is a speaker on a telephone), phr. **used by the speaker to announce his identity.**

So, if you are going to phone to someone on the phone, then "May I speak with...?" sounds like the most appropriate one.

Comment: Not in UK English. "Talk to" is almost universal, "speak to" a little more formal, and "speak with" is rare.