# About "talking X"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, expressions, colloquialisms

I have come across normal usage like "let us talk **about** science" or "he is talking funny". In the first case, what we are going to talk **about** is science. In the second case, he is not talking about sense. It is only a Description or Adjective or Style of what he is saying. We can even consider "he is talking funny about science", where the style is funny and the topic is science.

I have recently seen some TV shows or NewsPaper articles which drop **about** where it seems to be required. Eg "talking movies" instead of "talking about movies", or "talking music" instead of "talking about music".

What is this **grammatical concept** known as ? Is it a recent occurrence ? How widespread is this usage ? Is there some case where this formation becomes ambiguous and **about** is mandatory ?

COMMENT : Here I am talking **about** grammar ; I hope I am talking sense.

Comment: ***Talk  [+ object]*** : *to have a conversation about (something).*  They are in the conference room talking business. They were talking baseball/politics. (M-W). *Talk business, talk politics *: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talk+business%2Ctalk+politics+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalk%20business%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalk%20politics%3B%2Cc0 - I think it is just one ordinary usage of "talk"*.

Comment: It's pretty informal, despite the fact that it may be used by the press. My inclination would be to say that it's an Americanism, possibly derived from a manner of speech common to (and probably originated by) blue-collar workers: "Look at the size of that guy's forearms - we're talking gorilla, here."

Comment: @Oldbag I don't see it at all as an Americanism. It is perfectly idiomatic in Britain to say *We are talking business/science/politics/football etc* It is equally idiomatic to say we are *talking about* any and all of those things.

Comment: @WS2 In fact, the only such collocation I can think of where _about_ doesn't work at all is ***talk shop***; but then that's an idiom, so it doesn't really count.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between “speak” and “talk”, grammatically speaking?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140463/whats-the-difference-between-speak-and-talk-grammatically-speaking).  // Note that there is a constraint on acceptable 'objects' (which are probably better considered as adverbial objectives, reduced prepositional phrases): Let's talk money. / ??Let's talk weather. /  *They're talking me/Peter. // But what connection have adverbs of manner (eg funn[il]y)?

Comment: @Janus 'Let's talk turkey' is also quite different from 'Now, the new recipes we've been looking at. Let's talk about turkey.' And OP's 'talk sense' is another idiom (= 'talk in a sensible way' rather than 'talk about sense').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's talk X** (and similar constructions)

where X is a noun phrase, has a variety of possible interpretations / possible substitutions for 'talk', depending on the nature of X. These structures certainly look like transitive usages of 'talk', though how useful the 'verb + DO' analysis really is (they talked tripe / *tripe was talked by them / *did they talk it) for individual senses is arguable. From [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talk):

> **talk** v.tr.
>
> 1. To utter or pronounce (words): *Their son is talking sentences now.* [*Don't talk tripe.*]
>
> 2a. To speak about or discuss (something) or give expression to
>   (something): *talk business*; *talk treason*.
>
> b. Used to emphasize the extent or seriousness of something being
>   mentioned: *The police found money in the car. We're talking
>   significant amounts of money.*
>
> 3. To speak or know how to speak (a language or a language variety): *The passenger talked French with the flight crew. Can you talk the local dialect?*
> 4. To cause (someone) to be in a certain state or to do something by talking: *They talked me into coming*. [*He's talking her to death.*]

Sense 2a seems an obvious deletion of the preposition 'about' so that 'talk' is used at least superficially like 'discuss'. Prepositional deletion is not uncommon (I'll see you [on] Tuesday; they entered [into] an agreement; ...). It is often used to create a punchier variant. But being in the modern idiom, it may not sound natural when used with some older / traditional referents.

These [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%27s+talk+money%2Cthey%27re+talking+politics%2Cwe%27re+talking+business&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20talk%20money%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20%27re%20talking%20politics%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20%27re%20talking%20business%3B%2Cc0) for "let's talk money", "they're talking politics" and "we're talking business" show that sense 2a above has been in use for quite a long time. General trends are hard to spot.

My impression that examples of sense 2a are widespread and common is supported by largish numbers of Google hits for "talking politics"; "talk money" ....

There **are** constraints on the actual noun phrase chosen. These seem to be for more subtle reasons than the avoidance of ambiguity.

> Let's talk hip-hop.
>
> ?Let's talk plainchant. (incongruous)
>
> ?/??Let's talk weather. (unnatural sounding)
>
> *Let's talk Mr Lee / the Simpsons / me.

Comment: Good answer Mr. Ashworth. This clarifies things for me, I thought I was dealing with a simple idiomatic expression. Thanks.

Comment: @Edwin , thanks for the comprehensive answer. I want to echo the comment by "Little Eva" that this clarifies a lot of things. Your response also has some pointers for me to follow eg "Prepositional Deletion".

Comment: @Little Eva Isn't a 'simple idiomatic expression' often one that people haven't made an attempt at the derivation of? [see eg Shrobe](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JaCjBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=inexplicable+idiom&source=bl&ots=8cSQa-hACF&sig=nC_RK-zNgqO4QBzRLQEX9c8kLq0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBmoVChMIg8aF6bSRxgIV5K7bCh0s-gA6#v=onepage&q=inexplicable%20idiom&f=false)

Comment: On numerous occasions since I began hanging-out at this place, that has certainly proven to be the case. Often it seems that the closer I look the more I find. Thanks for the missing-link, Mr. Ashworth. ;-)

Comment: Are you questioning my ancestry? :-(