# Speak to or talk to?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Consider this: I call my friend at his home and his mother picks up. What is the right thing to say?

Hello, may I speak **to** Daryl? Or

Hello, may I talk **to** Daryl?

Similarly,

Hello, may I speak **with** Daryl? Or

Hello, may I talk **with** Daryl?

The choice of words always gets me thinking during a phone call. Which of these should be used?

Comment: Related: 1. [“Speak to” vs. “Speak with”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with) 2. [What's the difference between “speak” and “talk”, grammatically speaking?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140463/whats-the-difference-between-speak-and-talk-grammatically-speaking?lq=1) 3. [What is the difference between “speaking” and “talking”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/what-is-the-difference-between-speaking-and-talking)

Comment: Related: [Is there any difference between "talk to someone" and "talk with someone"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-there-any-difference-between-talk-to-someone-and-talk-with-someone)

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why I didn't come across it earlier.